# Not getting the value in return value from store props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Comment } from './../components/comment';

class Comments extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const { logStatus } = this.props;
        console.log(logStatus ); //consoles
        return(
            <div>
                I am Comment page {logStatus}  xx //getting empty
                <Comment />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    logStatus:state.loggedIn
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Comments);
```

I am trying to get my `logStatus`  in the template. but not works. I am getting consoled. any one correct me the mistake please?

thanks in advance.

Comment: try using template literal ``I am Comment page ${logStatus}``

Comment: your state is undefined, if you change logStatus:state.loggedIn into logStatus:"someString" the logStatus will prints. can you show the reducer/ combined reducer for this ?

Comment: @Ramesh - No luck. tried

Comment: @Viraj - but how i am getting value consoled

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my boolean value as string, it works fine.

before:

```
const initialStore = {
    loggedIn:false
}
```

updated to: works fine. any one help me to understand the issue here?

```
const initialStore = {
    loggedIn:'false'
}
```

Comment: Maybe react can't convert type boolean to string when we use `{}` syntax, generally the content of any tag is a string so I guess react expects you to pass a string. If you want to keep `loggedIn` as a boolean and still use it inside your template then you can use `I am Comment page { logStatus ? 'true' : 'false' }`.